# Clean ldap installation|setup ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ldap, client

I want to remove the installation of ldap client in Ubuntu 14.04.

When we install ldap client so:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-ldap libpam-ldap ldap-utils
```

A screen is displayed as shown in the [link](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_14.04&p=ldap&f=2):

If something goes wrong, we uninstall and start again, but in the 2nd time don't show the screen. How to clean the installation?? or How to setup ldap client man

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure ldap-auth-config